# Slicing a Pandas dataframe with a multiindex by combinations of level values

Tags: pandas, slice, multi-index

I 'm looking to slice a Pandas dataframe with a multi index by a list of values for some of the index levels.

```
import pandas as pd
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product((('A','B'),
                                    range(2),
                                    ('c','d')))
df = pd.DataFrame(index=index,columns=range(2))

slice_list = [('A',0),('B',1)]
```

This doesn't work:

```
df.loc[slice_list,:]
```

I can get my expected result by doing boolean masking(?):

```
idx = (((df.index.get_level_values(0) == 'A')
   & (df.index.get_level_values(1) == 0)) |
   ((df.index.get_level_values(0) == 'B')
    & (df.index.get_level_values(1) == 1)))
df.loc[idx]



         0    1
A 0 c  NaN  NaN
    d  NaN  NaN
B 1 c  NaN  NaN
    d  NaN  NaN
```

But I would much prefer a slicing option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) with remove last level for 2 levels `MultiIndex`:

```
df1 = df[df.index.droplevel(-1).isin(slice_list)]
print (df1)
         0    1
A 0 c  NaN  NaN
    d  NaN  NaN
B 1 c  NaN  NaN
    d  NaN  NaN
```

Details:

```
print (df.index.droplevel(-1))
MultiIndex([('A', 0),
            ('A', 0),
            ('A', 1),
            ('A', 1),
            ('B', 0),
            ('B', 0),
            ('B', 1),
            ('B', 1)],
           )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas.IndexSlice` (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IndexSlice.html).

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
slice = idx[['A','B'],[0,1],:]
df.loc[slice,:]
```

Or something along those lines, I am currently replying from a cell phone so I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but I'm not looking to get all cells that have either 'A' or 'B' as their first index and either 0 or 1 in the second index, but specifically cells with 'A',0 or  'B',1 in the first two indices.